# Problem with counting child divs of one level out of parent div in Selenium Java

Tags: java, html, css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

It is my first post here so please advise if I'm not too specific.

Problem:
On "https://justjoin.it/all-locations/testing/with-salary_yes" site I am trying to get number (count) of div child div elements from a parent div. Parent is a list of advertisiments leveled one under another.

Solution I use:

```java
WebElement adsList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]"));
List<WebElement> ads = adsList.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]"));
    int adsCount = ads.size();
```

For this solution particular solution I either get value 0 in return or error finding selector.

Comment: How could we _possibly_ help with this, based on the info you have provided so far? _"I've tried this solution with numerous selectors"_ - we don't know _what_ you tried, and we don't know what HTML/DOM structure this is supposed to work on in the first place.

Comment: This should help you put a snippet into your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If the URL of the website is public, share it in your question and point to the elements you are trying to locate. If the URL is private, share the HTML of the website in the text format. Also, show us the XPath expressions which you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi. Thank for replies. The link is "https://justjoin.it/all-locations/testing/with-salary_yes" and xpath to the "parent" element I was asking about is "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]"
all the ads within this element I would like to treat like child